# How do you link MS Access 2016 to Visual Fox Pro dbf tables as linked tables?

Tags: vba, ms-access, visual-foxpro, dbf, linked-tables

I have a Visual FoxPro set of tables (.dbf extension) which I want to create linked tables to in MS Access. The forums I have checked seem to indicate that the vfpodbc.dll is no longer supported. I have installed the new OLE driver, but it does not appear as an option in the Linked table manager for selection. I can access this driver from Excel 2016.

Question: 
Am I limited to using the programatic link method via VBA or is there a way to get this to work using the Linked table manager?

My OS is Windows 10. 
Visual FoxPro Software is "INFUSION version 8.414"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the FoxPro OLEDB driver, you will have to connect programmatically. There's no way to link tables the way you can from an ODBC data source.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Dropped it's support since MS Jet 2.6, but you can try to use [Advantage Database Server OBDC driver](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?key=20&Release=19&Product=14)